# html page failing to display rupee currency symbol

Tags: html, xslt, encoding

I have a database configuration table that holds the rupee symbol `&#8377`.

when my page loads a java class reads this value using jdbc from the sql server database and using xslt transformation displayed in a table.

there are no issues with the $ UK pound symbol etc, but rupee will not display. In the table I see that the value `&#8377` is displayed and when I view the source I see that the text has been escaped to `&amp;#8377`.

If I edit the source in chrome and change `&amp;#8377` back to &#8377 it displays fine, I'm trying to work out how to prevent this escaping from occurring.

I have tried to escape the & with `\&#8377`however this is still encoded to`\&amp;#8377.`

I have also tried directly sticking the `&#8377` into the xslt sheet in line with some text like:

```
<h2>Some text (&#8377)</h2>
```

but with this it displays as 'Some text (?)'

There must be a simple solution to this one but I've not found anything so far :(

Comment: Isn't the Rupee sign ₨ `&#8360;` ?

Comment: no 8377, looks like i've found a potential solution within the xslt which is disable-output-excapting="yes". it appears to be working on the initial tests

Comment: another possible is <xsl:output method="text"> but this appears to apply to the whole document which is not what i want

Comment: It would help seeing an example of your input and your stylesheet (including the header). -- To add the sign with no relation to the input, try: `<h2>Some text (&#8377;)</h2>` (note the closing semicolon).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty rectanglar box is displayed instead of the rupee symbol in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643675/empty-rectanglar-box-is-displayed-instead-of-the-rupee-symbol-in-html)